# Image mask without transparant part

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I've been looking into this for a while now.

I'm trying to put a gray image over a cup

[image]

Currently i'm stretching an uiimageview with a grey background to the amount the slider has gone.

```
-(void) sliderChanged:(CGFloat) value{
drinksView.grayArea.frame = CGRectMake( 0 , -value ,372 ,value);
```

I know this is very dirty ,not what i want...

**What i want is that the grey part only covers the part where there is a cup (e.g the part where the image is not transparant)**.  The image of the cup just has a transparant background

Does anybody have an idea of how to achieve this ? i'm a noob with masks and many tutorials have led me nowhere and i don't even know if it's possible.

P.S:  drawing a path around the cup is not possible because the cup image can change to a glass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to use a masked CALayer. This is what you need to do:

1. Instead of using a `UIImageView`, use a `CALayer` with gray background as your overlay. Your `sliderChanged:` method would remain untouched, except that `drinksView.grayArea` would be a layer instead of a view.
2. So far the effect will be exactly the same as before. Now, you need to set the `grayArea`'s mask. Do the following:

   ```
   CALayer * maskLayer = [CALayer new];
   maskLayer.contents = myCupImage.CGImage;
   grayArea.mask = maskLayer;
   ```
3. I think by default the layer will stretch the content as the scale is changed. We don't want that. You can fix this by setting the layer's `contentsGravity` to, say, `kCAGravityTop`.

That should do what you want.

One caveat: I'm not quite sure how masks cope with changing content gravity. If you have issues on that front, you can fixed it by adding a container layer:

1. Set a fixed frame for `grayArea` (equal to the size of the cup image).
2. Instead of adding `grayArea` directly, introduce a container layer for it:

   ```
   CALayer * container = [CALayer new];
   container.masksToBounds = YES;
   [container addSublayer:grayArea];
   [drinksView.layer addSublayer:container];
   ```
3. In your `sliderChanged:`, change the frame of `container` instead of the `grayArea`.

Hope this works.

Comment: this worked like a charm , i'll post my final code at the bottom cuz it did need some enhancements.

Ty very much

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will need to get familiar with this method

```
    // masks the item based on the MaskImage
- (UIImage*) itemMask : (UIImage*)image withMask:(UIImage*)maskImage
{
    UIImage* afterMasking = nil;

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef), CGImageGetHeight(maskRef), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef), CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef), CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    CFRelease(mask);
    afterMasking = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
    CFRelease(masked);
    return afterMasking;
}
```

What that does is that you feed it your Cup image and the mask Image together and it will mask your cup image. It will only mask your cup image and nothing underneath so you don't have to worry.

The problem you have is that the grey box resizes. How I would approach this is to crop the mask according to the slider value. So make a black box and change it size how you do with the grayBG BEFORE you feed it through the method. That should be quick to do so so I won't elaborate but at the end you will have something like this. Pardon the half elaborated graphics

[image: Image With large slider][image: Image With small slider]

Comment: Since the first answer worked for me, i did not try this (fixed price project ;) )    Thanks for the effort anyways

Answer (score 0):

```
    drinksView.grayLayer = [CALayer new];
    drinksView.grayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 372, 0);
    drinksView.grayLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityTop;

    CALayer * topLayer = [CALayer new];
    topLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 372, 367);
    UIImage * grayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"grayDrink.png"];
    topLayer.contents = (id) grayImage.CGImage;

    CALayer * maskLayer = [CALayer new];
    maskLayer.contents = (id)cupImage.CGImage;
    maskLayer.masksToBounds = YES;

    maskLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 372, 367);
    maskLayer.position = CGPointMake(186,184);

    [topLayer setMask:maskLayer];
    [drinksView.grayLayer addSublayer:topLayer];
    [drinksView.grayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [[drinksView layer]addSublayer:drinksView.grayLayer];
```